# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist Error

Tags: django

Here is the model. I have created my own user model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    favorite_food = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.user.set_password(raw_password)
```

Here is the view:

```
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'templates/core/profile_form.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            user = form.save(commit=False)

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Here is UserForm

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'favorite_food']
```

Where seems to be the problem here? It also says that `Profile has no user` I have tried changing it to AbstractUser however, it also displays about an error about reverse accessor

Comment: Do you create a user with your view or just update it?

Comment: I'm trying to create an instance of a user

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude user from form and add save method to the form:

```
    class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
        username = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

        class Meta:
            model = Profile
            fields = ['username', 'password', 'favorite_food']
            exclude = ['user']

        def save(self, user = None, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=False):

            username = self.cleaned_data['username']
            password = self.cleaned_data['password']

            profile = super(ProfileForm, self).save(commit=commit)
            if user:
                profile.user = user
                profile.set_password(password)

            profile.save()
            return profile
```

In you view:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        profile = form.save(user = request.user, commit=False)
```

Comment: are you sure that you have user attached to the profile? did you check it?

Comment: Is it this one? 'user = models.OneToOneField(User)'

Comment: yes. can you check if user attached to the concrete instance of profile?

Comment: Ok. I have seen that inside Profile model you have this field declared. But when you edit the instance of the profile are you sure that you user field is not empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157752/discussion-between-jm-lontoc-and-alexander-tyapkov).